# Failed to construct 'FormData'

Tags: javascript, dropzone

When I upload file in my dropzone, it do not work. Usually it's work very well, but since 1 month I have this JS Error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'.
```

That is the code, when I use FormData :

```
 var form_data = new FormData("#my-awesome-dropzone");
```

Dopzone code

```
  Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
    maxFilesize: 5,
    maxFiles: 1,    
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    dictResponseError: 'Server not Configured',
    acceptedFiles: ".pdf",
    init:function(){
      var self = this;
      // config
      self.options.addRemoveLinks = true;
      self.options.dictRemoveFile = "Delete";
      //New file added
      self.on("addedfile", function (file) {
          console.log('new file added ', file);
             if(!confirm("Do you want to upload the file?")){
                this.removeFile(file);
                return false;
            }

      });
      // Send file starts
      self.on("sending", function (file, xhr, formData) {
        console.log('upload started', file);
        $('.meter').show();

            var form_data = new FormData("#my-awesome-dropzone");

            $.ajax({
                url: '/settings/uploadFile', 
                data: 'file=' + file.name ,
                type: 'POST',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(response) {
                }
            });
      });
      
      // File upload Progress
      self.on("totaluploadprogress", function (progress) {
        console.log("progress ", progress);
        $('.roller').width(progress + '%');
      });

      self.on("queuecomplete", function (progress) {
        $('.meter').delay(999).slideUp(999);
      });
      
      // On removing file
      self.on("removedfile", function (file) {
        console.log(file);
      });
    }
```

HTML CODE

```
     <form  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/settings/uploadFile"  method="post" class="dropzone" 
                        id="my-awesome-dropzone">

         
                     </form>
```

**Edit 01-08-2019** : Okay, just tested, and it's works on Microsoft Edge 44.17763.1.0 but not on Google Chrome or Firefox, any explanation?

Comment: Could you also attach the HTML?

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). Although Stack Snippets disallow *submitting* forms, as you can see from the live example in my answer, you can still create `FormData` and so should be able to replicate the problem.

Comment: Okay, I will try to make an example for my case. But I think it's up of browser no ? Because my code use to works on all Browsers, and now it's works only in Microsoft Edge, why ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You're passing a **string** to [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData). As the error says, it expects a form element, not a string. So:

```
var form_data = new FormData(document.getElementById("my-awesome-dropzone"));
```

Live Example:

```js
var data = new FormData(document.getElementById("my-awesome-dropzone"));
console.log("Created FormData, " + [...data.keys()].length + " keys in data");
```

```html
<form  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/settings/uploadFile"  method="post" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone">
<input type="text" name="x" value="kittens">
<input type="text" name="y" value="puppies">
</form>
```

Comment: @MasterSinge - Then your element with `id="my-awesome-dropzone"` isn't a `form` element, or it doesn't exist (yet) when this code runs, which would make `getElementById` return `null` [which also causes this error when passed to the `FormData` constructor]).

Comment: @tjcrowder - When I console log, it return data =>  [link](https://i.ibb.co/FWsy1w1/toto.png)

Comment: This error also occurs if you do not have <form> tags defined in your html but you are calling new FormData on a different element id.

Comment: @MasterSinge - If I copy the `form` HTML from your question and paste it into a file, and copy the code from the answer above into a `script` in that file (after the `form`, so I know it exists), it works a treat on Chrome.

Comment: my mistake was that I had a form inside another