# I would like to send a FORM DATA by POST by JS.However all input elements of the form will be empty

Tags: javascript, php

I made a form tag and script.
I tried to send POST.  However, The formData is empty.
I do not know why.

HTML code

```
<form id = "form" action="sample.php" method="POST">
<input name="mytext" type="text">
<input id="submit-button" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

JavaScript code

```
const form = document.getElementById("form")
const submitButton = document.getElementById("submit-button")

submitButton.onclick = () => {
  event.preventDefault()
  var request = document.createElement('input');
  const formData = new FormData(form)
  const action = form.getAttribute("action")
  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
  }
  fetch(action, options).then((e) => {
    if (e.status === 200) {
      alert("sent")
      return
    }
    alert("fail")
  })
}
```

PHP code

```
  $text= $_POST['mytext'];
```

I put console.log(formData) in   fetch(action, options).then((e) => {}
.As far as I can see,formData is empty.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzLCs.png)

I tried to use

```
  const f1 = document.getElementById('mytext');
  const fd = new FormData(f1);
```

instead of

```
const form = document.getElementById("form")
```

However, this error happened.

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'.
> at submitButton.onclick (test.php:213:14)

Comment: Can you update your code such that it better resembles a [mre]? It's not clear where in the DOM you've got your script running, which is imperative to understanding whether your first two `getElementById()` calls will actually return anything. How do you *know* definitively that "*The formData is empty*"? What did you expect to happen, and what *actually* happened? Please review [ask]

Comment: How do you know definitively that "The formData is empty"? 

I checked   $_POST['mytext'];  it was blank.

Comment: You should call `event.preventDefault()`  in the click handler. Otherwise the form will be submitted normally and the page will reload.

Comment: If you view the body data in the Network tab of Developer Tools, do you see the data being sent?

Comment: I have checked formData by console.log. I can't seem to find anydata. I think JavaScript did not get form content.

Comment: Where can I see the formdata? in PHP or HTML I can see payload tab However ,In the post by JavaScript  Payload tab does not exist.

Comment: Updated question is now a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57285984/failed-to-construct-formdata

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `event.preventDefault()` to your function, if you don't the form will cause the page to reload and no data would be sent.